# What's going on with JSON.stringify(arguments)?

Tags: javascript, json, arguments

Why doesn't arguments stringify to an array ?

Is there a less verbose way to make arguments stringify like an array?

```
function wtf(){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments));
  // the ugly workaround
  console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
}

wtf(1,2,3,4);
-->
{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4}
[1,2,3,4]


wtf.apply(null, [1,2,3,4]);
-->
{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4}
[1,2,3,4]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w7SQF/

This isn't just to watch in the console.  The idea is that the string gets used in an ajax request, and then the other side parses it, and wants an array, but gets something else instead.

Comment: because [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is an Array like Object, not an Array. you could do `[].slice.call` instead of `Array.prototype.slice.call`

Comment: Yes, that would be shorter and have less MSG. Thanks.

Comment: What you could also do: `arguments.toJSON = [].slice; console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments));` :-)

Comment: @Bergi Nice!, I dind't knew you can assign a `toJSON` function to an Object, good to know, thanks =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's happening because arguments is **not** an array, but an [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments). Your workaround is converting it to an actual array. JSON.stringify is behaving as designed here, but it's not very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify([...arguments]));